# How to Use Autofac to Register Generic Actions?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

[Edited with more details at commenter request]

If I have the following:

```
myClassInstance.Register<MyCommand>(new MyCommandHandler().Handle);
```

I could of easily repeated the line above in different handlers.

However, I wonder is there a way to use Autofac to register them all generically through convention?

Here is code reflecting existing non-DI code:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IMockBus bus = new MockBus();

        var eventStore = new EventStore(bus);
        var repository = new Repository<InventoryItem>(eventStore);

        // Command
        bus.RegisterHandler<CreateItem>(
            new CreateItemCommandHandler(repository).Handle);

        // Event
        bus.RegisterHandler<ItemCreated>(
            new ItemCreatedEventHandler().Handle);
    }
}

public interface IMockBus
{
    void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : IMessage;
}

public interface ISendCommands
{
    void Send<T>(T command) where T : Command;
}

public abstract class Command : IMessage
{
}

public interface IMessage
{
}

public interface IPublishEvents
{
    void Publish<T>(T @event) where T : Event;
}

public class Event : IMessage
{
    public int Version;
}

public class MockBus : IMockBus
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IMessage>>> routes = 
        new Dictionary<Type, List<Action<IMessage>>>();

    public void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : IMessage
    {
        List<Action<IMessage>> handlers;

        if (!routes.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out handlers))
        {
            handlers = new List<Action<IMessage>>();

            routes.Add(typeof(T), handlers);
        }

        handlers.Add((message => handler((T)message)));
    }
}
```

Comment: does `MyCommandHandler` implement some generic interface?

Comment: What is the definition of `MyCommandHandler.Handle`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I've added the interface to the question.

Comment: Does this code compile? How are you mapping the `MyCommand` type to a method? Can you provide more complete code?

Comment: Trying to figure out why you are wanting to register the method, and not just all commands like this:  `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyCommand<>)).As(typeof(IHandle<>));`.  The consumer of this receives an `IHandle` and calls `Handle()` presumably - or I've totally missed something

Comment: @BrendanGreen, all commands and events like this. They all work the same so I thought that would be easy enough to wire up through Autofac.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I've added full code for you to look at. Left out classes not relevant like EventStore.

Comment: Shameless plug but I wrote a blog post about this very thing quite recently - http://www.ramblingincode.com/building-a-command-pipeline-with-autofac/

Comment: Must your `RegisterHandler()` take an `Action<T>`?  If it was able to take instead an `IHandle<T>`, which is what your interface is, it would be simpler perhaps

Comment: I have managed to register all my commands and events, etc with: builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IHandle<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces(); but now no idea how to resolve the list of handlers in order to call them :)